# Is there a Python Library that calculates TFIDF from a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module, tf-idf

Is there a Python library or module that can calculate td/idf from links in a text file? I have heard of scikit but I am not sure how it would work with a text file.

Comment: This looks promising: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting - If you have a specific question, we need to see what you've tried so far and where you get stuck.

Comment: My main issue is that my links are stored in a set as opposed to a dictionary. I believe that is where I am having my issues.

Comment: You can get items from a set by converting it to a list: myset = set([1,2,3])
print list(myset)[0]
# prints 1. If this gets any deeper, we'll need to see some code and context.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this and see if it works